# Building MariaDB on s390

Tags: linux, mariadb, mariadb-connector-c

I'm trying to build mariaDB on s390 (z/Linux) following these instructions
[mariaDB Instructions](https://github.com/linux-on-ibm-z/docs/wiki/Building-MariaDB-10.x). Sorry, I'm not much of a DBA or a SA.

But I got stuck in the step "3.7 Create database and populate test data into database"

```
sudo scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql
```

This is the error I got:

```
root@tdpvld01:/usr/local/mysql> sudo scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql
Installing MariaDB/MySQL system tables in '/var/lib/mysql' ...
2019-03-05  9:17:57 6 [ERROR] Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20. Created with MariaDB 50552, now running 100312. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error
2019-03-05  9:17:57 6 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.event: expected column 'sql_mode' at position 14 to have type set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','IGNORE_BAD_TABLE_OPTIONS','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','STRICT_ALL_TABLES','NO_ZERO_IN_DATE','NO_ZERO_DATE','INVALID_DATES','ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO','TRADITIONAL','NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER','HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE','NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION','PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH','EMPTY_STRING_IS_NULL','SIMULTANEOUS_ASSIGNMENT'), found type set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','IGNORE_BAD_TABLE_OPTIONS','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALU
ERROR: 1136  Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
2019-03-05  9:17:57 0 [ERROR] Aborting


Installation of system tables failed!  Examine the logs in
/var/lib/mysql for more information.

The problem could be conflicting information in an external
my.cnf files. You can ignore these by doing:

    shell> scripts/mysql_install_db --defaults-file=~/.my.cnf

You can also try to start the mysqld daemon with:

    shell> ./bin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --general-log &

and use the command line tool ./bin/mysql
to connect to the mysql database and look at the grant tables:

    shell> ./bin/mysql -u root mysql
    mysql> show tables;

Try 'mysqld --help' if you have problems with paths.  Using
--general-log gives you a log in /var/lib/mysql that may be helpful.

The latest information about mysql_install_db is available at
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-system-tables-mysql_install_db
You can find the latest source at https://downloads.mariadb.org and
the maria-discuss email list at https://launchpad.net/~maria-discuss

Please check all of the above before submitting a bug report
at http://mariadb.org/jira
```

As suggested in some forums, I tried to run mysql_upgrade. But got this error:

```
root@tdpvld01:/usr/local/mysql/bin> ./mysql_upgrade
Version check failed. Got the following error when calling the 'mysql' command line client
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You didn't mention which Linux distro  you're running on Z; but chances are you don't need to compile anything?  http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=mariadb

Comment: Sorry for that, it is Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)
The latest RPM version for Red Hat I found, was 5.5

Comment: Perhaps you need connection arguments (user/pwd/port/...) on the call to `mysql_upgrade`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was rather simple.
There was a previous mysql/mariadb rpm installation on that s390. I uninstalled the mariadb RPMs, but left mysql.
It seems that when I compiled mariadb, it overwrote mysql installation and generated that errors.
I uninstalled everything, recompiled again and now its working fine.